# How to define the "smoothness" of a line?

Tags: functions, terminology, smooth-functions

I'm looking for a way to define some sort of a *smoothness value* for each point on a line. Then I would in turn define the smoothness of a closed loop to be the smoothness of its least smooth point.

Maybe "smoothness" is not the right term here. The intuition I have in my mind is a loop that is made from steel wire or some similar flexible material. Tension inside the wire would cause the curvature of the loop to be roughly the same at each point. If I cut the loop open, the steel would return to be just a straight line segment.

To demonstrate what I mean, take [these equations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+sin%282t%29cos%28t%29%2C+y+%3D+sin%282t%29sin%28t%29) for example:

$$
\begin{align}
x & = \sin{2t} \cos{t} \\
y & = \sin{2t} \sin{t}
\end{align}
$$

On the plot below, it *seems* like the curves around the centre point are smoother, while the curves around the four edges are less smooth.

[image: Plot from WolframAlpha]

For instance, if I drew a tangent at the edges, it would seem like I'm getting away from the edges faster as I move along the tangent, compared to if I drew the tangent through the $x$ or $y$ axis.

At the same time, if I draw a circle, the smoothness value appears to be the same at each point.

[image: Circle plot from WolframAlpha]

So, my questions would be:

1. Is there a name for this "smoothness value" that I am thinking of?
2. If so, how do I calculate it at each point for a given set of equations, e.g. for my four-leaf clover above?
3. How would I continuously deform my line towards a local maximum of such a smoothness value? Basically, how do I smooth out those edges?

I'd give the second two questions a stab myself but I'm stuck with number one.

Comment: I think you mean the second derivative.

Comment: Now I feel dumb… I was looking at second derivatives earlier today but the intuition did not come through.

Comment: ... or curvature

Comment: There is a notion of *curvature* for a curve. For a circle, this is exactly the reciprocal of the radius so that smaller curvature implies 'less curvedness'. And this notion generalizes to a wider family of curves, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Plane_curves) for instance.